# Map XKB level without preserving modifier

Tags: xkb

I'm trying to map Super+V to XF86Paste:

```
default partial xkb_types "mine" {
  type "MY_SHIFT_SUPER" {
    modifiers = Shift+Mod4;
    map[None] = Level1;
    map[Shift] = Level2;
    map[Mod4] = Level3;
    # ???
    level_name[Level1] = "Base";
    level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
    level_name[Level3] = "Super";
  }
}
```

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "mine" {
  include "latin"
  # ...

  key <AB04> {
    type = "MY_SHIFT_SUPER",
    symbols[Group1] = [ v, V, XF86Paste ]
  }
}
```

This works in that I get `Super+XF86Paste` when I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, but I want just `XF86Paste` alone.

I have tried replacing `# ???` with:

- `preserve[Mod4] =;` - this didn't seem to result in any error, but it was bound to `v`;
- `preserve[Mod4] = None;` (a stab in the dark, I don't know that `None` is supposed to be valid here) which bound to `Super+XF86Paste` still

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Actually, it seems it is correctly consumed by default without `preserve`, it's just that Alacritty's still picking up the modifier. https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/5972

Comment: And I meant to ask (thought I was asking) this on Unix & Linux SE, not Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Nicely answered at askubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002792).

For your purpose, it'll be something like this:

```
key <AB04> {
    type = "MY_SHIFT_SUPER",
    symbols[Group1] = [ v, V, NoSymbol ]
    actions[Group1] = [ NoAction(), NoAction(),
            RedirectKey(key=<XXXX>, clearmods=Mod4) ]       };
}

// pick an unused key, instead of XXXX
key <XXXX>{ [XF86Paste] };
```